# Rails: Open link in a new page

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, link-to

I was wondering a way to open a link in a new tab. Here is the code I have so far:

```
<li><%= link_to "Pictures", pictures_path  %></li>
```

I have researched ways to do this with `target="_blank"`, but for some reason when I tried it, it did not work. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: What didn't worked when you tried `target="_blank"`?

Comment: When I clicked on the link It did not open in a new tab

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try it like this:

```
<li><%= link_to "Pictures", pictures_path, target: :_blank %></li>
```

Comment: Ah Thank you! This worked just how I wanted it to. Problem solved :)